# Setting Exif data on image always return error on Android 7

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, exif, android-gps

I have to set exif data on my Image. in Android 8 my code works fine but in Android 7 It report the error below and after that no exif data are saved on image:

> W/ExifInterface: Given tag (GPSLatitude) value didn't match with one of expected formats: URATIONAL (guess: STRING)

This is my code:

```
    public void geoTag(String filename, double lng, double lat){
    ExifInterface exif;

    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
        int num1Lat = (int)Math.floor(lat);
        int num2Lat = (int)Math.floor((lat - num1Lat) * 60);
        double num3Lat = (lat - ((double)num1Lat+((double)num2Lat/60))) * 3600000;

        int num1Lon = (int)Math.floor(lng);
        int num2Lon = (int)Math.floor((lng - num1Lon) * 60);
        double num3Lon = (lng - ((double)num1Lon+((double)num2Lon/60))) * 3600000;

        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, num1Lat+"/1,"+num2Lat+"/1,"+num3Lat+"/1000");
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, num1Lon+"/1,"+num2Lon+"/1,"+num3Lon+"/1000");
   ...........
```

Comment: `num1Lat+"/1,"+num2Lat+"/1,"+num3Lat+"/1000")` Sorry. We dont know what you want to set. Please give the string value. Post reproducable code.

Comment: Hi, I want to set longitude and latitude for an image that I have on Gallery. The code is above and it works, but only with Android Oreo (api 26). See my answer below...for string value, but repeat it's very strange.

Comment: You only repeated yourself. We knew that all. You did not give the info i asked for. We canotgive help then.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The fix is to use long instead of double for num3Lat and num3Lon. Cast to long and all works great

Answer (score 0):

@greenapps....thank U for your time. Basically I have my code that retrieve position from map and save on SharedPref :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="LatLng">11.812703;42.081890</string>
</map>
```

After that, I have a method that split that string in the longitude and latitude:

```
    public final void notifyMediaStoreScanner(final File file,Activity mainActivityCatched) {
    double longituderetrieve;
    double latituderetrieve;
    try {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mainActivityCatched.getContentResolver(),
                file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), null);
        mainActivityCatched.sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  //  SharedPref getPosition = new SharedPref(mainActivityCatched);
    SharedPreferences getLatLng = mainActivityCatched.getSharedPreferences("settingModeLatLng",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String LatLngShared = getLatLng.getString("LatLng","currentLatLng");
    latituderetrieve = Double.parseDouble(LatLngShared.substring(0,LatLngShared.indexOf(";")));
    longituderetrieve = Double.parseDouble(LatLngShared.substring(LatLngShared.indexOf(";")+1));

    try {
        geoTag(file.getAbsolutePath(),longituderetrieve,latituderetrieve);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

...finally I pass all values to another method to set position in exif data. My original code was:

```
 public void geoTag(String filename, double longi, double lati) throws IOException {


         ExifInterface exif;
 try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
        int num1Lat = (int)Math.floor(lat);
        int num2Lat = (int)Math.floor((lat - num1Lat) * 60);
        double num3Lat = (lat - ((double)num1Lat+((double)num2Lat/60))) * 3600000;

        int num1Lon = (int)Math.floor(lng);
        int num2Lon = (int)Math.floor((lng - num1Lon) * 60);
        double num3Lon = (lng - ((double)num1Lon+((double)num2Lon/60))) * 3600000;

        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, num1Lat+"/1,"+num2Lat+"/1,"+num3Lat+"/1000");
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, num1Lon+"/1,"+num2Lon+"/1,"+num3Lon+"/1000");


        if (lat > 0) {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "N");
        } else {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "S");
        }

        if (lng > 0) {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "E");
        } else {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "W");
        }

        exif.saveAttributes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PictureActivity", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

The strange thing with my code is in Android api26 works....
Any suggestion is very appreciated!
Alex